Is There an ESLint Rule to Require Parenthesis Around Conditions?
I want to be able to enforce parens around conditions in my JavaScript project with ESLint.
if ((condition1 === "yes") && (condition2 === "no")) {
    // Do something
}

The following should produce an error and ESLint should be able to automatically "fix" it with --fix.
if (condition1 === "yes" && condition2 === "no") {
    // Do something
}

I have been unable to find a rule that works for this. Is there currently any ESLint rule that can achieve this?

None that I know of. Why do you want this?
